# How to Fetch User Data Using Firebase and Vuejs

Tags: firebase, vuejs2

I have project called meetup app, this project taken from youtube tutorial. Everything working as I expected, but iIhave problem because of this method. I can't display profile user page here on below the code :

> folder store/join/index.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'
import 'firebase/storage'

export default {
  actions: {
    fetchUserData ({commit, getters}) {
      commit('setLoading', true)
      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + getters.user.id + '/registerations/').once('value')
        .then(data => {
          const dataPairs = data.val()
          let registeredMeetups = []
          let swappedPairs = {}
          for (let key in dataPairs) {
            registeredMeetups.push(dataPairs[key])
            swappedPairs[dataPairs[key]] = key
          }
          const updatedUser = {
            id: getters.user.id,
            registeredMeetups: registeredMeetups,
            fbKeys: swappedPairs
          }
          commit('setLoading', false)
          commit('setUser', updatedUser)
        })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            commit('setLoading', false)
          })
    }
  }
}
```

I can't display specific user profile when they login into my meetup app such as dsplay email, displayName and photoURL. The question is how to do that, sorry if my english language poor. thanks in advance

Comment: That method looks fine. Do you have the user id in your state.user? What do you get if you console.log(state.user) in the getter 'user'?

Comment: Sorry i am late... this is my profile picture https://imgur.com/a/ZEpEBkT  and this is my store/user/index.js link:  https://pastebin.com/9Q4Mwkp8